# Facing trouble in position of content of WKWebview which is inside scrollview with other views while I rotate my screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wkwebview

I have added view, wkwebview and tableview inside scrollview. Its display all the content properly when loaded. But When I rotate the phone content position of wkwebview did not match. And display content which is in center of wkwebview.

Any one have idea about how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please elaborate...

Comment: can you plz share your code or screenshot here?